# Korean rice cakes (tteok) sold unrefrigerated

Tags: food-safety, rice, korean-cuisine

I bought some tteok, cylindrical Korean rice cakes, that were displayed on a table. It didn't have a date on it. They seem to need soaking before cooking as they are not very soft but only packaged in a Styrofoam container with plastic wrap.

Is this safe to eat (there was no date on it) or is this the old rice left out issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are completely dry, that's fine; you can buy hard dried tteok and they are shelf stable. But if they are moist, that seems very unsafe to have sitting out at room temperature for an indeterminate period of time.

Comment: I was sure of that, and that I had seen them dry and on the shelf, but I could not for the life of me find a reference. I'm so glad you were able to answer. I'll just add what [Serious Eats](http://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2014/03/tteokbokki-from-the-worlds-best-spicy-food.html) has to say about my favorite way to prepare it.